# DataStax java.lang.AssertionError: Invalid offset

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We are running a 3 node cluster for testing. So this is not a production architecture that we have as a plan.

What I have observed is that this in the debug.log. Also after this, DataStax is not able to do compaction of the table, in which the issue is unless I restart the node

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Invalid offset: 3814, buf: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=3514 cap=4096], bh: ChunkCache$Buffer(/var/lib/cassandra/data/databasename/tablename-4d572062e99311e8ae3c232aeb4f8023/aa-70906-bti-Partitions.db@135168)
```

I tried searching for this error but could not find the answer to it anywhere

Most surprising part is that there is no such file as

```
aa-70906-bti
```

in the folder /var/lib/cassandra/dataname/tablename

I see files with higher number like 72096 or so

Comment: what version of DSE are you using?

Comment: DSE 6.0.4 version

Comment: can you paste log somewhere, like, pastebin?

Comment: @AlexOtt here you go https://pastebin.com/xW89v0T9

Comment: @AlexOtt let me know if you know, I can share more and can give all debug files

Comment: Thank you very much! I've passed it to dev team

Comment: If you dev team wants, they can write to us and we can give them cluster credentials to login and see

Comment: Can you write me to alexott at gmail - I’ll connect you to our dev team...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the report, this was a bug in the interaction of two different kinds of early open for levelled compaction. The bug has been fixed for DSE 6.0.5.

Meanwhile, if you need to work around the problem, set `sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb` in `cassandra.yaml` to something large, e.g. 100000. This will disable early open on incomplete files, but enable it for completed sstables and work around this problem, but still get almost all of the performance advantages of early open.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like that you hit a [known bug that was fixed in the DSE 6.0.4](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/releaseNotes/RNdse.html#RNdse604__604H) with offset calculation:

> Fix wrong offset in size calculation in trie builder. (DB-2477)

Please upgrade to 6.0.4 to fix this issue.

Comment: I can share debug log if required